# How would you iterate through every character in a string in React? (i.e. without a for loop)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I've found that you can't use either the "forEach" or "map" functions on strings, so how would I go about going through every character in a string within JSX? Thanks for any responses.

I want to put a space between every character in a word e.g. "dog" -> "d o g".

Comment: @TKoL I'm sure there's a duplicate but that one is pretty old and doesn't cover the functional iteration builtins very well

Comment: This question should not be tagged “react” or “jsx”. All processing is JavaScript related. The fact that the output can become part of the render process of a React app is totally tangential.

Comment: @Pointy - Can always add an answer that does. :-)

Comment: Yes that's true, but on those hoary old questions new answers generally languish at the bottom of the page and nobody (especially new users) will see them.

Answer (score 5):

You can call `.split("")` to turn the string into an array of characters, and then use `.forEach()` or `.map()` or whatever.

```
var s = "Hello world";
s.split("").forEach(character => console.log(character);)
```

Answer (score 3):

> I want to put a space between every character in a word e.g. "dog" -> "d o g".

That can be done with:

```js
const input = "dog";
const output = input.split('').join(' ');
console.log(output);
```

Split turns the string into an array, breaking it every time it sees a certain character. Since we're splitting on an empty string, we get an array of each character on its own.

Join takes an array and turns it into a string, putting the specified character in between each element of the former array.